# React Native call function from navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using React native navigation. (Stack Navigation).
But I can't call function in navigationOptions. Not working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, AsyncStorage, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import HandleBack from '../../HandleBack';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: 'Dasboard',
            headerLeft: null,
            headerRight: (
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={this.login.bind(this)} style={{marginRight: 10}}>
                    <Icon
                        name="power-off"
                        size={25}
                        color="white"
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            )
        };
    };

    login() {
        alert('Button clicked!');
    }

    onBack = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3');
    };    

    render() {        
        return(
            <HandleBack onBack={ this.onBack }>
                <View>
                    <Text> This is screen 2 </Text>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}> 
                        <Text> Go to Screen 3 </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </HandleBack>
        )
    }
}
```

When I'm using `onPress={this.login.bind(this)}` get error

*"TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluatinh '_class.login.bind')"*

When I'm using  `onPress={this.login}` no reaction.

When I'm using `onPress={this.login()}` get error

TypeError: TypeError: _class.login is not a function.

**But**

I'm using `onPress={() => alert('test')}` is working.

Comment: Try removing `static`

Comment: Then navigationOptions does not work.

Comment: you will never have context of this inside a `static` function, unless you pass it explicitely

Comment: This is a react-native-navigation error or bug.

Comment: btw where are you are calling `navigationOptions`

Comment: this is how any static keyword in any language works, if you can tell where exactly are you calling this func maybe I can be of some help

Comment: How do I search for a function here? This is necessary.

Comment: @warl0ck It says the code above.

Comment: I meant where are you calling this function `navigationOptions` ?

Comment: No, I can't call

Comment: what do you want to do in that function? @Dodiş if you want to redirect to any screen then you can directly use navigation params

Comment: What is the use and purpose of `navigationOptions` where you are calling it and tell why it can't be without `static`

Comment: @PatelDhara No. I'll do a Token check. Then the logout process.

Comment: I think you are using 'react-navigation' not the 'react-native-navigation'. And if that's the case then this type of question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058740/react-native-call-screen-function-from-header

Comment: You're right Thank you. @AnkitMakwana

Comment: @Dodiş In fact this is very well documented on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component

Comment: @AnkitMakwana Yes, I need to read more carefully. You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can achieve it using setParams or getParams for react-navigation.

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {


    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: 'Dasboard',
            headerLeft: null,
            headerRight: (
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' 
                 onPress={navigation.getParam('login')} //call that function in onPress using getParam which we already set in componentDidMount
                   style={{marginRight: 10}}>
                    <Icon
                        name="power-off"
                        size={25}
                        color="white"
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            )
        };
    };
   login() {
        alert('login click')
    }
    onBack = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3');
    };    

componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ login: this.login }); //initialize your function
    }
    render() {        
        return(
          .....
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you consider this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725635/method-is-not-being-invoked-when-i-press-the-button and tell me what i am doing wrong !