# Method is not being invoked when i press the button

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-thunk, react-navigation-stack

I am using react navigation and have added a button on the right to signout from my app using default navigation options as shown below :

```
const otherApp = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome : { 
    screen : WelcomeScreen
  }
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions : ({navigation}) => ({
    title : 'Welcome',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#29434e',
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      elevation: 0
    },
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', padding: 5 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.getParam('logout')}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
          }}>
          Logout
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  })
});
```

And i am binding the method to be invoked as follows :

```
_Logout() {
    this.props.signOut();
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ logout : this._Logout.bind(this) })
  }
```

Function is maped to props using the redux

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    Signout : ()=> dispatch(Signout())
  }
}
```

But the problem is when i press the button, it does not invoke the method !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, what i was doing wrong that i wasn't passing a call back in the onPress of the button !

```
logoutFromFirebase = () => {
    this.props.Signout();
    this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.user.uid ? 'App' : 'Auth')
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ logout : this.logoutFromFirebase })
  }
```

And default navigation

```
defaultNavigationOptions : ({navigation}) => ({
    title : 'Welcome',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#29434e',
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      elevation: 0
    },
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', padding: 5 }}
        onPress={navigation.getParam('logout' , () => Reactotron.log('Logout not callled'))}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
          }}>
          Logout
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  })
```

And now it is working fine !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `onFocus` method of `react-navigation` to see whether the screen is on focus or not. If the screen is on focus then call the function.

```
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
 componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

export default withNavigation(Your Class Name);
```

Method : 2

```
import { NavigationEvents } from "react-navigation";

 onFocus = () => {
 //Write the code here which you want to do when the screen comes to focus.
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigationEvents
          onDidFocus={() => {
            this.onFocus();
          }}
        />
)}
```

Comment: what is meant by the "didFocus"  in addListener ?

Comment: didFocus means whenever the screen is in focus that particular function will be called. It has other methods too like didBlur, willBlur etc. Please refer to react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html for complete set of functions available.

Comment: the class is already exported wrapped with redux connect how i can wrap it with navigation ?

Comment: i want to add a button on the header of the component which will call redux funtion, not the way you are telling me !

Comment: i have edited the question, you can recheck now what is going on here !