# Link a function to onPress headerRight button

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

While creating stack navigation I needed to add a `save` button to the `headerRight`. Here is the code for the navigation stack:

```
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name='Clients' component={ClientSrc} options={({ navigation }) => ({
                title: 'My Clients',
                headerRight: () => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddClients')}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/addClient.png')} style={styles.addBtnImg} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
            })} />
            <Stack.Screen name='AddClients' component={AddClientSrc} options={({ navigation }) => ({
                title: 'Add New Client',
                headerRight: () => (
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.headerButtton} onPress={() => WHAT_TO_DO_HERE}>Save</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            })} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
```

The `AddClients` screen has a **Save** to the right side of the navigation bar that'll save the data in text fields. When the `Clients` screen navigate to `AddClients` I can see the `Save` button appearing. Now, I want to run this function on `AddClients` screen when the **Save** is pressed.

```
const saveData = () => {
    console.log('The Save button is being pressed')
}
```

As I've defined the `headerRight` for both `Clients` and `AddClients` inside the `Clients` screen, so how can I call the save button in `AddClients` file? Or is there a proper way to do this? The `WHAT_TO_DO_HERE` in the code snippet is where I've no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to take an approach similar to this.

Here we update the header from the effect using setOptions, the dependency to text is required otherwise your state change wont be reflected when you press the button.

Basically we set the button and other header options from the screen itself instead of setting them when we initialize the stack.

```
function AddClientSrc({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Updated!',
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text onPress={() => onSaveClick()}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [text]);

  const onSaveClick = () => {
    alert(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>AddClientSrc</Text>
      <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={setText} placeholder="Enter text" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly invoke the function from options, you should try with the setParams and getParams-
follow this thread [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725635/method-is-not-being-invoked-when-i-press-the-button)

and for direct invoking the function, try to make a custom header.